# Scheduling a task to run semi-randomly

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks

On Windows 10, what would be the best way to schedule a task to run indefinitely, with a random interval between 15 and 60 minutes each time? For example, if the scheduling was activated at 13:00, the task could run at 13:20, 14:05, 14:21, 15:01, 16:01, 16:27 etc. To my knowledge, the Windows Task Scheduler allows only for completely defined intervals, such as "every hour".

Comment: The Linux solution to this kind of problem is to schedule the task to run on the hour, but break the task into 2 parts - a random wait time followed by the actual command.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would just write a script that performs the task at the random intervals necessary.  Alternatively, you can use the script to *create* the scheduled tasks.  Or, you could just run the script, and have the task scheduler check if the script is running and start it, if it isnt.

There are other task schedulers out that you can use, besides Windows' built in scheduler.  See some [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=better%20windows%2010%20task%20scheduler&oq=better%20windows%2010%20task%20sc&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j33l6.7151j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).  I have never used them, but perhaps one or more has some form of randomization that you can use.